# Custom routing in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have created two different cases of map routes in routeconfig.cs.

```
// case 1
routes.MapRoute("Default2","{x}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
// case 2
routes.MapRoute("Default3","{controller}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
```

The question is if I use case 1 and input is `example.com` then the url pattern is not matched even though default controller and action is provided

for the case 2 and input is `example.com` it fires default controller and action. Why does that happen?

I believe that must happen with case 1 also but what could be the reason? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remember that MVC routing evaluates from top to bottom, thus route with x parameter will evaluate first before default controller. If you want default value for x, place `new { x = 'Home' }` in your parameter defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case:

```
// case 1
routes.MapRoute("Default2","{x}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
```

You are not defining a default value for the placeholder `{x}`, therefore this route **requires** exactly 1 segment (that can contain *any value*) in order to match the URL. So it will match `/foo` or `/bar`, but will not match `/` or `/foo/bar`.

In this case:

```
// case 2
routes.MapRoute("Default3","{controller}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
```

You *are* supplying a default value for `{controller}` which takes effect when it is not supplied in the URL. Therefore, it will match the URL `/` and will route to the `HomeController.Index` method in this case.